# How to use variables in a loop with consecutive numbers in their names?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, test-bench

As mentioned in the question, i want to use variables in a loop with consecutive numbers in their names, the code is as follows：

```
`define VAR(idx) a_``idx
`define VAR_STR(idx) $psprintf("ENV_PATH.a_%0d", idx)

initial begin
    int a_0;
    int a_1;
    int a_2;
    int sum;
    
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) begin
        //Method 1：No doubt it's wrong
        sum = sum + `VAR(i);
        
        //Method 2: Negative, uvm_hdl_read can't access env path
        int tmp_val;
        uvm_hdl_read(`VAR_STR(i), tmp_val)
        sum = sum + tmp_val;       
    end
end
```

So, is there a way to achieve the above requirement? Or is this even possible?

I have tried both of the above methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1 never works because macros get expanded into text as your code gets compiled, not as they are procedurally executed. `` `VAR(i) `` gets expanded to `a_i`, and `a_i` was never declared.

Method 2 should have worked if the path is correct *and* you have provided VPI access to the path.

Comment: Thanks dave. I read some of your papers on VPI. Your answer and papers are very helpful. But one more question: does the VPI access path need to be added manually? It would be nice to have a simple code example

Comment: @Jack VPI access is a tool specific command line option, normally `+acc` or `-access`. Check your tool's user manual. For best simulation performance you grant access to just the paths you need. Otherwise you can give global access.

Comment: I added ```acc``` to the options, and use ```get_type_name()``` to get access path, but still no success. Here is my code [VPI UVM test at EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/JHEU). Could you tell me where the bug is?  Thanks a lot

Comment: You have an almost entirely new question. You cannot `force` a member of class. (See section _6.21 Scope and lifetime_ in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595). Also the string returned by `get_full_name()` is invented by the UVM, it is not how SystemVerilog sees the path.